# Powershell split & trim to remove blanks and commas

Tags: powershell, variables, split, trim

I have the output from an az command that gives me somwhere like 50 lines, I want to feed each line into a foreach loop to change some config. Problem is each line ends in a comma and the start and end of the output has a [ ] character. As an example

```
[
  "/subscriptions/11c112-f823-4d5a-8615-8b96d08caf35/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/website-name-1",
  "/subscriptions/11c112-f823-4d5a-8615-8v9f9s9a9c9a/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/website-name-2",
  "/subscriptions/11c112-f823-4d5a-8615-8b96d08caf35/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/website-name-3"
]
```

I need to finish with a list containing new lines of only the text within the " ", I've tried saving this as a variable and doing $variable.split(",") but this gives me no commas, a blank line between each and I still have the [] characters. Can someone help steer me?

Comment: You may share the command you're using to get this output. There might be a better way  to get this output in the right way in the first place than doing some string acrobatics afterwards.  ;-)

Comment: The result of your command is a json representation of an array. Did you look at [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a Json output, the best thing you can do is to convert your json string to a PSCustom object representation with the `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` function.

These will allow you to convert the Json string into an object, do the desired manipulation easily without dealing with character escaping and working with the string directly.

Then, when you are over, if you need a Json again, you can convert it back easily. `ConvertTo-Json` will take care of everything (character escaping, formatting, etc...) for you.

Here is an example.

```
$AzCommandOutput = 
@'
[
  "/subscriptions/11c112-f823-4d5a-8615-8b96d08caf35/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/website-name-1",
  "/subscriptions/11c112-f823-4d5a-8615-8v9f9s9a9c9a/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/website-name-2",
  "/subscriptions/11c112-f823-4d5a-8615-8b96d08caf35/resourceGroups/resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/website-name-3"
]
'@  | ConvertFrom-Json

$MyArray = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]]$AzCommandOutput


for ($i = 0; $i -lt $MyArray.Count; $i++) {
    # Do needed manipulation
    $MyArray[$i] = $MyArray[$i] -replace 'resource-group-name','My-Resource-Group'
}

#If ever you need the oputput in json format again... 
$NewOutput = $MyArray | ConvertTo-Json
```